# Is this Seal of Prophethood hadith authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Is this hadith authentic:

> Shama'il Muhammadiyah » Seal Of Nubuwwah (Prophethood) Of Rasoolullah
>
> 'Ilbaa bin Ahmar Al-yashkari says that the Sahaabi, Abu Zayd 'Amr bin Akhtab Al-Ansaari Radhiallahu Anhu said to me:
>   "Rasullullah (Sallallahu alaihi wasallam) once asked me to massage his waist. When I began massaging the back, accidentally (by chance) my fingers touched the Seal of Prophethood. 'Ilbaa (Radhiallahu anhu) says: 'I asked Amr (Radhiallahu anhu), what is the Seal of Prophethood?' He replied: 'It was a collection of few hair'".  ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/urn/1800190))

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the narrator chain then the narrators are all considered as trustworthy (as one may easily check [here](http://hadithportal.com/index.php?show=bab&bab_id=2&chapter_id=0&book=131)).

Let us now check whether the chain is connected:
Imam at-Trimidhi has narrated this hadith trough:

- Muhammad ibn Bashar al-'Abdi (also known as **Bundar** بُنْدَارٌ) [محمد بن بشار](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A8%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1) a known trustworthy hafidh of hadith from Basra (who didn't travel elsewhere to seek knowledge). Some said that foreign people used to seek him in first place for hadith while the people of Basra used to seek abu Musa (a contemporary). At-Tabarni  narrated that ibn Ma'yn considered him as weak and ibn al-Madini quoted a hadith he was narrated that was rejected by abu Dawood. However high scholars such as the authors of the two sahihs and the sunan have compiled his hadith (For details see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=2180&bk_no=60&flag=1) in a-Dhahabi's Syar A'alaam an-Nubala').
- **Abu 'Asim** (also known as ad-Dahhak ibn Makhlad an-Nabil) [أبو عاصم النبيل](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%84). He was among the oldest teachers of al-Bukhari and a teacher of scholars like imam Ahmad, Ishaaq ibn Rahawayh, al-Asma'i, **Bundar** ... he is considered as trustworthy and a faqih (see also [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=1621&bk_no=60&flag=1) in Syar A'alaam an-Nubala').
- **'Azra ibn Thabit** al-Ansari عزرة بن ثابت الأنصاري (also known as ibn abi Zaid) was a scholar from Basra who was considered as trustworthy by an-Nasa-i, abu Dawod, ibn Ma'yn and ibn Hebban. He was a among the teachers of **abu 'Asim** and 'Abdullah ibn al-Mubarak. (For details see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=1857&pid=652483) in [al-Mizi's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yusuf_ibn_Abd_al-Rahman_al-Mizzi) Tahdeedb al-Kamal).
- **'Ilya' ibn Ahmar al-Yashkuri**  علباء بن أحمر اليشكري is another scholar from Basra and a teacher of **'Azra ibn Thabit** al-Ansari. Muslim, an-Nasa-i, at-Tirmidhi and ibn Majah have compiled his hadith. Ibn Ma'yn, abu Zur'a. (For details see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?hflag=1&bk_no=1857&pid=652673) in Tahdeeb al-Kamal).
- Abu Zayd 'Amr ibn al-Akhtab al-Ansaari عمرو بن أخطب الأنصاري is considered from among the sahaba who settled down in al-Basra. Among his students was **'Ilya' ibn Ahmar**. His hadith is compiled in hadith books with the exception of those of imam al-Bukhari (For details read [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=396&bk_no=60&flag=1) in Syar A'laam an-Nubala').

So we may conclude that this hadith has a Basri-Narrator chain and it is connected as teacher and student (the transmitters) have met each other seemingly (this would mean that the conditions of both al-Bukhari and Muslim are met, see [What exactly are the conditions of al-Bukhari and Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/what-exactly-are-the-conditions-of-al-bukhari-and-muslim)).

Note that this hadith appears in other sources such as Musnad al-Imam Ahmad, al-Hakim's al-Mustadrak, Tabaqat ibn Sa'ad and ibn Hebban with a slightly different wording and was printed in a book called sahih a-Sham'ail al-Muhammadiyah (see [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi03IjhnIzbAhUJ6CwKHTZaCgc4ChAWCCYwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alukah.net%2Fbooks%2Ffiles%2Fbook_1847%2Fbookfile%2Ftrue%2520merits%2520mohammedia.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0-rx79Xxx_Amsm98o2V529) hadith 14) which is based on Mukhtassar a-Shama'il al-Muhammadiyah (a summary of imam at-Tirmidhi's book see [here](https://archive.org/details/FP9550) hadith 17) of sheikh al-Albani so the hadith might at least reach the level of Hassan. Al-Albani said that ibn Hebban and al-Hakim considered it as sahih and a-Dhahabi has affirmed this view and it is on the condition of imam Muslim.