# What did the seal of prophet hood look like?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets

According to tradition there was a marking on the prophet's back from birth or later between his shoulder blades, that wise men looked for and saw that confirmed to them his prophet hood even before he received the first revelation.

Is there any description of this marking?

Comment: Could you add the tradition as a reference in your question?

Comment: Related: [Is this Seal of Prophethood hadith authentic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37095/17163)